# NullPointerException with no real reason

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
    Character c = null;
    if (c != 'P') c = 'G';
```

Here's a simple code that is killing me with the results. Instead of the condition, I get an error NullPointerException. Although null! = 'P' and the condition must be fulfilled. I struggle with the problem of additional verification c! = null in condition "if". Is it should be? Are there any ways to make the comparison instead of an error? So it turns out that all the code just full of these unnecessary checks.

Comment: Try `!c.equals('P')`. Note that in practice you shouldn't use `Character` like that.

Answer (score 8):

To expand slightly on nansen's answer, your code is equivalent to:

```
Character c = null;

char tmp = c.charValue();
if (tmp != 'P')
{
    c = Character.valueOf('G');
}
```

This is according to [section 15.21.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) (`==` and `!=`):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

Hopefully now you'll see why you're getting a `NullPointerException`. Do you *need* `c` to be of type `Character` rather than `char`? If you really do, you should use:

```
if (c == null || c != 'P')
```

Comment: @LewsTherin: Sorry, typo - the comparison should have been against `tmp`

Answer (score 7):

You are using autoboxing, the wrapper type Character which is null is implicitly converted to a primitive char. That's when the NPE is happening.

Comment: @RNJ: right, but I believe the term autoboxing is used to summarize both directions of boxing.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare and object with a primitive. Java can only compare two elements of compatible types, thus it will not create an instance of `Character` with `'P'`, but will try to convert your variable `c` into a `char` and cannot do it because it is `null`.

Comment: if (c.equals(new Character('P'))) -> NullPointerException, if (c.equals('P')) -> NullPointerException

Comment: @user1221483, yes because `c` is null

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the '[Yoda Conditional](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)' syntax:

```
Character c = null;
if (!new Character('P').equals(c)) c = new Character('G');
```

This will mean that NullPointerException can never be thrown, as `null.equals()` is not valid, whereas `new Character('P')` can never be null.